# Passing space seperated strings in make commands from bash

Tags: bash

I am trying to pass space separated variables in double quote to make command

```
cat test.sh

test1="\"localvar1 localvar2\""

make -j8 SAN_TAR="$test1"
```

but shell executes it as

```
make -j8 'SAN_TAR="localvar1 localvar2"' #single quote between san_tar
```

Is there a way where i can pass it like

```
make -j8 SAN_TAR="localvar1 localvar2"
```

thanks in advance

Comment: What's wrong with `test='localvar1 localvar2'` and `make -j8 SAN_TAR="$test"`?

Comment: i have to pass it inside double quote. so make should read it as make -j8 SAN_TAR="localvar1 local var2" ( double quote should also be passed along with localvars so that make can expand space separated variables passed in SAN_TAR (what ever inside double quote)

Comment: Why do you need it? What do you want to do with it in the makefile?

Comment: That because make command makes a build based on number of parameter passed in SAN_TAR, if SAN_TAR=localvar1 it build for one target and if SAN_TAR="localvar1 localvar2" then it build for two target

Comment: What do you mean by "build for two targets"?

Comment: by two target i mean 2 variants. Internally make will run with different options passed in SAN_TAR. I dont have the control of makefile as it belongs to third party so not sure how they are expanding the parameter passed in SAN_TAR

Answer (score 0):

Don't put quotes inside the string.

```
test1="localvar1 localvar2"
make -j8 SAN_TAR="$test1"
```

The quotes around `$test1` keep the argument as a single string.

If `SAN_TAR` is being expanded inside the makefile in a place where a single string is needed, you could put single quotes in it:

```
test1="'localvar1 localvar2'"
make -j8 SAN_TAR="$test1"
```

Comment: i have to keep it as single string "localvar1 localvar2" have to be passed like a single string. Basically make should take a SAN_TAR as "localvar localvar2" inside a double quote.

Comment: Maybe putting single quotes inside the variable is what you need, see the update.

Comment: It would help if you showed the actual value you're trying to use, and how the variable is used inside the makefile.